# Display all items in the terminal with mailchimp API in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

I'm using mailchimp to display all my email address from an audience, to do so, I'm using this code:

```
const client = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

client.setConfig({
apiKey: "MY API KEY",
server: "MY SERVER",
});

const run = async () => {
const response = await client.lists.getListMembersInfo("LIST MEMBERS CODE");
i = 0
while (i < response.members.length){
   finalObject = Object.values(response.members[i]);
   console.log(finalObject[1]);
   i++
   }
};

run();
```

"MY API KEY", "MY SERVER" and "LIST MEMBERS CODE" are fake one here, I have the real ones in my code.

My problem is that the terminal only display 10 items, and I have 1058 `total_items` .
I know that the problem is `count`  that is 10 by default but I don't know how to change it because I don't have any URL to call the API.

Is there any other way to display all items by changing the number of `count` ?

I also know that the maximum items to display is 1000 so I have to do it twice to display all 1058 items.

Answer (score 2):

Examination of the relevant method [here](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-node/blob/master/src/api/ListsApi.js) indicates that you can supply a second parameter, an object. In your case, it would be:

```
{'count': 1000}
```

Thus the call would be:

```
const response = await client.lists.getListMembersInfo("LIST MEMBERS CODE", {'count': 1000});
```

See **[MailChimp API Reference](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/)** for more parameters.